# fontdrvhost.exe consuming high CPU and lots of RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, fonts, high-cpu-usage

I have a Windows 10 Professinal (build 1809) system which shows the following effect: Directly after a user logs on to the system, the process fontdrvhost.exe causes 60-80% CPU usage and a memory footprint (private bytes) of 2.5 Gig of RAM, slowing the system down significantly.

When I kill the process in taskmanager, the performance gets better for a short period of time, and then the process is restarted, showing the same effect again.

I have searched the internet, found a few similar desciptions but without solutions. What could be the reason for the effect, and how can I troubleshoot it or narrow down possible sources for this behaviour? I checked the fontdrvhost.exe in c:\windows\System32, which has a valid Microsoft SHA-256 signature, so I think this file cannot be infected with some virus.

Thank you for any hints you can give.

Comment: Have you cleared the font cache yet? Also, how many fonts are installed on the system? Could any of them potentially be faulty?

Comment: Do you have Office installed?